# Где поставить запятую возле И?

Tags: грамматика

Есть предложение: *Я думаю, что мясо и мясные продукты содержат необходимый белок для здоровья человека и что это пища, которую нужно употреблять.*

Где правильно поставить запятую:

- перед "и": *Я думаю, что мясо и мясные продукты содержат необходимый белок для здоровья человека, и что это пища, которую нужно употреблять* (потому что "что это пища..." — это отдельное предложение)
- или после "и" перед "что":
  *Я думаю, что мясо и мясные продукты содержат необходимый белок для здоровья человека и, что это пища, которую нужно употреблять* (потому что здесь перечисление: я знаю что делаю и что не делаю)?

Или здесь вообще не нужна запятая?

Заранее спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 3):

*Запятая не нужна,* поскольку придаточные, начинающиеся со "что", однородные (относятся к "думаю"): *Я думаю, что мясо... и (я (также) думаю) что это пища...* Придаточное *"которую нужно употреблять"* в свою очередь подчинено второму "что".

Похожий пример есть [здесь](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/752-25_slozhnopodchinennye_predlozheniya_s_neskolkimi_pridatochnymi_razbor_i_znaki_prepinaniya.html):

> *Отец мой говорил мне, что он не видывал таких хлебов и что нынешний год урожай отличный.*